# Should you be able to access your modem's web interface when the internet is down?

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem

I have a Motorola MB7621 Cabel-Modem and D-Link AC1200 Router with Xfinity internet. I have been experiencing problems where my WiFi will be down for a few hours before coming back up. I have already tried restarting and factory resetting both the modem and router. Additionally, I know the problem is not a system wide outage because the XfinityWifi public network from other connections in my building works.

My main concern is whether the problem is being caused by a faulty internet connection to the coaxial outlet in my wall or the modem/router. Recently, I noticed that when the internet is down I can access the router web interface but not the modem web interface. During these times, the router "Online" light is blinking indicating that it is trying to go online and the "Upstream" light is blinking green indicating ranging in progress. Of course, when the internet is working I can access both. Should I be able to access the modem web interface if the problem is with the connection coming to my wall outlet? Or does this indicate that my modem is the problem and needs to be replaced?

Comment: You should be able to log into the D-Link Router whether you have internet or not. The modem, if property of the ISP (normal), then they manage it. If it is yours, you should be able to access the modem management page whether you have internet or not.

Comment: @John I originally had an Xfinity router/modem combo but ended up buying my own. So based off the fact I can't always access my modem management page my modem is broken?

Comment: It is possible the modem has a hardware issue. I cannot tell from the above. Perhaps try a reset to factory settings to see if that clears up the problem. Look in your modem documentation for resetting it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends, if it's just the "internetconnection" to your ISP that is disconnected and not the modem itself is up and running (the networkinterface to your local network or the "webserver" inside the modem that's resposible for the web interface) you should be able to access it through it's "local" IP adress, depending on how your modem is set up.

With more information e.g. on how exactly you access it normaly we should be able to give you more specific instructions. Some words on how exactly they are connected and set up (including the device you are using to access them) would be helpfull as well.

Comment: The coaxial outlet in my wall in connected to the modem which is connected via Ethernet to my router. I access my router by 192.168.0.1 and modem by 192.168.100.1.

Comment: whats the subnet mask? 255.255.255.0? is the modem
'

Comment: what's the subnet mask? is the modem's IP fixed? whats your device IP (propable s.th. like 192.168.100.x)? Can you ping your modem when everything is running? Can you ping your modem when the internet connection is down?